# placeholder focus not working

Tags: html, css

The Placeholder color is red. The default text field value is #444. What I want, If i click the text field, the placeholder color will change.  But the default color should not be changed. Is it possible to do?

Please see my fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/ca35A/

```
CSS:
.add_product input[type=text]{ color:#444;}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #D72D2E;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: #D72D2E;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: #D72D2E;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: #D72D2E;  
}




::-webkit-input-placeholder:focus {
   color: #F3797A;
}

:-moz-placeholder:focus { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: #F3797A;  
}

::-moz-placeholder:focus {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: #F3797A;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder:focus {  
   color: #F3797A;  
}
```

Comment: The placeholder color should change? But the placeholder will disappear when you focus the field.. `:focus` is on an `input` not on a `placeholder`.

Comment: @putvande Actually not: it will only disappear if you start typing...

Comment: It depends on the browser. In IE it disappears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `:focus` before `::placeholder`:

```
:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder //etc
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ca35A/1/

Comment: It looks like changing placeholder when focusing input field. isnt?

Comment: Yes, it means "placeholder within an element that has pseudo-class :focus" instead of "a placeholder that is focused" in the original code.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the `:focus` on the `placeholder` but it should be on the `input`:

```
:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #F3797A;
}

:focus:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
    color: #F3797A;
}

:focus::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
    color: #F3797A;
}

:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #F3797A;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ca35A/2/)

Note that not all browser support this. IE for example hides the `placeholder` when you focus on the `input`.